# Dropdown delete divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

İ have a dropdown menu with select options and datepicker input fields.

```
<select class="form-control" name="child" id="children" required>
   <option value="1" selected>Çocuk</option>
   <option value="2">1</option>
   <option value="3">2</option>
   <option value="4">3</option>
 </select>
```

when the selection is changed every time, I would like to show a number of datepicker fields, corresponding to the selected option.

```
    $("#children").change(function () {
  $("#childrenlist > :input").remove();
  var numInputs = $(this).val();
  for (var i = 1; i < numInputs; i++)
    $("#childrenlist").append('<div class="col-2"><div class="input-group date" id="bornpicker' + i + '" data-target-input="nearest"><div class="input-group-prepend" data-target="#bornpicker' + i + '" data-toggle="datetimepicker"><i class="input-group-text fa fa-birthday-cake form-icons"></i></div><input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#bornpicker' + i + '" data-toggle="datetimepicker" name="childborn' + i + '" placeholder="Doğum Tarihi"  required></div></div>');
    $('#bornpicker1').datetimepicker({ locale: 'tr', maxDate: 'now', format: 'DD.MM.YYYY', viewMode: 'years' });
    $('#bornpicker2').datetimepicker({ locale: 'tr', maxDate: 'now', format: 'DD.MM.YYYY', viewMode: 'years' });
    $('#bornpicker3').datetimepicker({ locale: 'tr', maxDate: 'now', format: 'DD.MM.YYYY', viewMode: 'years' });
});
```

my problem with this

```
$("#childrenlist > :input").remove();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use this the funtion `.empty()` to empty your element `#childrenlist`.

## Look at this code snippet.

```js
$("#children").change(function() {
  $("#childrenlist").empty();
  var numInputs = $(this).val();
  for (var i = 1; i < numInputs; i++)
    $("#childrenlist").append('<div class="col-2"><div class="input-group date" id="bornpicker' + i + '" data-target-input="nearest"><div class="input-group-prepend" data-target="#bornpicker' + i + '" data-toggle="datetimepicker"><i class="input-group-text fa fa-birthday-cake form-icons"></i></div><input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#bornpicker' + i + '" data-toggle="datetimepicker" name="childborn' + i + '" placeholder="Doğum Tarihi"  required></div></div>');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="child" id="children" required>
   <option value="1" selected>Çocuk</option>
   <option value="2">1</option>
   <option value="3">2</option>
   <option value="4">3</option>
 </select>
 
 <div id='childrenlist'> </div>
```

See? now is adding the amount of `input` elements.

**Note:** I've removed the piece of code that adds `datetimepicker` elements for testing purposes.

Comment: thank you so much. i add 3 times datetimepicker cause if i do just one. datepicker working just 1 field

Comment: @LearninCode I've removed for testing purposes :-)... Your logic is OK!

Comment: @LearninCode if this answer has helped you, can you accept it?